# JDK7 install problems

Tags: java, java-7

Hi I Have just installed jdk 7 on my laptop as there were some new features i needed to make use of that in a program which i was writing. i downloaded the file from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html

and downloaded the one for 64 bit machines and 32 bit machines.

i tried using the 64-bit one but it gave me an error so i moved on to trying 
Windows x86 (32-bit)

and got the same error.

my classpath variable is

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\
```

and then i have another one called path which is

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Simatic OAM\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-StaticC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files\jEdit\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
```

and then one called QTJava (which i did not create or edit)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
```

My question is with the variables set as they are why is it when i try and run any java programs i get the error in the command window

```
Could not find or load main class programName?
```

when i type into the command line with commands listed below
javac

javac ButtonGridv3.java

java ButtonGridv3

i then get an error which says

Could not find or load main class ButtonGridv3

thanks

Comment: try putting semi-colon core-static in C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-StaticC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin

Comment: What's the error your getting?

Comment: Post exactly what you type into the command line to try running the program, and also post exactly what the error is.

Comment: Apart from other errors, remove the classpath variable, is not needed and it should not point to that folder.